# R Help keyboard shortcut in VScode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I have fully transitioned to VScode from Rstudi; however, one thing that I dont manage to figure out is how to set a keyboard shortcut  (Like F2 in Rstudio) within an .R or .rmd file in VScode. Right clicking on a function brings up the contextual menu with the option to "open  help for selection" (R help). I just don't know if there is a way to assign this to a keyboard shortcut.

[image: contextual menu]

Comment: all menu entries are bound to a commandId, search the key bind GUI for the text of the menu item, use that commandId for a key bind combo

Answer (score 0):

The ID of the command you're looking for to bind to a keyboard shortcut is `r.helpPanel.openForSelection`. You can find a list of commands by triggering suggestions in the keybindings.json file, or looking through the keyboard shortcut editor, or by looking in [the extension's manifest file](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/blob/master/package.json).